# How to add a wait in OnCollisionEnter Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code i am using and i am trying to add a wait inside of the if collision thing anyone know what to look into or a solution? i tried looking into coroutines and using bool values to try and do it that way but i couldnt figure it out any help or suggestions is appreciated!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SwordDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            collision.rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Checkout the answer from @JeffChen, there are other ways of doing it, but it's more complicated and less flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a coroutine from within OnCollisionEnter() to create a delay.

Some example code:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    StartCoroutine(DelayedAction());
    // coroutines must be called from StartCoroutine()
}

private IEnumerator DelayedAction() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    print("I was printed after a delay of 5 seconds!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was declaring the Enumerator wrong and i didnt realize

Comment: Actually `OnCollisionEnter` can be a Coroutine itself: `private void IEnumerator OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){ yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    print("I was printed after a delay of 5 seconds!"); }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can use:

```
OnCollisionStay(Collision collision) { }
```